# Using KDTree.query

Tags: python, numpy, kdtree

So I'm trying to run a nearest neighbor search and am starting off keeping it really simple. My array:

```
array = [([0, 0], 
          [0, 1],
          [2, 1])]
```

Then my code:

```
tree = spatial.KDTree(array)

dist, indices = tree.query(array)
print dist
print indices
```

What I can't understand is my output. My output is:

```
[0. 0. 0.]
[0 1 2]
```

Which I don't understand how it related to my system. The doc for query is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html)

Comment: You are finding the nearest neighbors of the same points you used to build the tree, so `[0,0]` is finding it's nearest neighbor to be `[0,0]` (which is index 0) at a distance of 0 away. The same is happening for the other points. Try giving a different query array than the one you used to build to test this

Comment: Ahhh that makes so much sense. So if I do 'dist, indice = tree.query((1,0))' it gives me 1 cause the nearest neighbor is 1 away and at indix 0